# Mp4 file stream from an android device

Tags: android, streaming

I need a way to stream an video file (.MP4, .AVI) **with audio** using rtmp protocol from an android device. essentially a stream like on YouTube or Twitch with an video playing on loop.

Comment: Welcome!  What is your budget?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.